# Eclipse check if something was refactored

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, refactoring

I am using a plugin which catches a lot of changes in the eclipse editor or other actions in other Eclipse views. For example, it describes in an activity log view, which file I opened, which file I changed, which file is focused and so on.

Now I have to extend this plugin and I had the idea to catch if something in the code was refactored with some of the refactoring methods in Eclipse (Extract Constant, Extract Local Variable, Rename Method, ...). My idea was, that the activity log shows messages like

> There is a refactoring in file X in row Y

or even

> There is a refactoring: Method 'oldname' was changed to 'newname'

My question is: Is there are a way to do this? I never programmed plugins or other kind of Eclipse extension. Therefore I don't know if my idea can be realized, thus if this kind of log messages are possible. If so, where can I start to look. I mean with which keyword can I google?

Comment: I think good idea would be to look at Refactor/History... its located in plugin with id=org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring. Writing eclipse plugin is not an easy task and I recommend reading about it online before you do it. eclipse eco system is complex and it takes time to understand it.

Comment: And is it possible to differ between refactor variants? I mean, can I figure out if someone used "Extract Constant" or "Change Method Signature" or "Extract Local Variable" and so on?